# drawing path in svg with 90° arc between perpendicular lines

Tags: html, svg

I would like to draw two perpendicular segments between 2 points in space.

Instead of a visual effect of 90° between the two points, I would like to draw an arc (quarter of a circle) to visually smooth the angle.

I struggle to understand how path could be shaped, if using bezier of arcs - could you show a solution and explain what parameters do ?

I also wonder how drawing paths behave computationally - how much do they perform paths with only M H V parameters, respect drawing arc or bezier curves?

I read guides but did not achieved results that I want yet.

---

Example:

so far I have :

```
// draw two perpendicular segments between points (0,0) and (100, 100)
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200">
        <path 
              d="
                M 0,0
                H 100 
                V 100
                 "
              />
    </svg>
```

That visually appears like broken line made by two perpendicular segments between points A(0,0) and C(100,100), that cross at B(100,0).

Now, I would like to draw two perpendicular segments between points A and C, and place a quarter circle arc instead of point B, **oriented** in a way that the two segments form a continuos line - not a "broken line" (not English native, I hope you understood what I mean by "broken line").

This is the neatest solution I came up with, but still not working:

```
// attempt to draw a " curve " between 2 perpendicular segments > failed

<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200">
        <path 
              d="
                M 0,80
                H 80
                Q 100,100 100, 100
                V 200
                 "
              />
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different people learn diferent ways, so take this as some general hints how to find out how path commands work:

- the primary source obviously is the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathData)
- Draw paths with a visual editor, and inspect the resulting code. [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) has a handy built-in XML editor that lets you see the rendered path and its definition side by side.

In your example I think the main problem was the use of the `H` and `V` commands. They are shorthands for the `L` commands, where either the x or y coordinate are left off and copied from the last control point. These two paths are equivalent:

```
M 0,80   L 90,80
M 0,80   H 90
```

as are these

```
M 100,90 L 100,200
M 100,90 V     200
```

For now, connect the two with a straight line segment:

```
M 0,80   L 90,80   L 100,90   L 100,200
```

Now, you have to exchange the straight line between `(90,80)` and `(100,90)` with a curve. It could be a quadratic bezier (second line is the shorthand form):

```
M 0,80   L 90,80   Q 100,80 100,90   L 100,200
M 0,80   H 90      Q 100,80 100,90   V 200
```

Thecurve starts at `(90,80)`, the middle control point sits at `(100,80)`, and the end is at `(100,90)`.

Or you could use a true arc:

```
M 0,80   L 90,80   A 10 10 0 0 1 100,90   L 100,200
M 0,80   H 90      A 10 10 0 0 1 100,90   V 200
```

Start and end points remain the same. The rest of that command is a bit more complex:

- first two numbers are the horizontal and vertical radius of the arc
- the third number would rotate these two axes, 0 says no rotation
- the 0 in fourth place says the arc goes less than 180 degrees around the ellipse (1 would mean > 180)
- the 1 in fifth place says the arc runs clockwise (1 would be anti-clockwise)

Complicated? The [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands) has a nice grafic to explain it.

```css
path {
    fill:none;
    stroke:black;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 200">
    <path d="M   0,80   L  90,80   Q 100,80 100,90        L 100,200" />
    <path d="M 100,80   L 190,80   A 10 10 0 0 1 200,90   L 200,200" />
</svg>
```

Comment: hey thank you @ccprog  - your explanations where the most clear I found. Actually for me it was a bit cumbersome, because I am working on a dynamic layout and had to think about rotations and positive and negative coordinates to properly orient the arc. 

So, could you maybe give a tip: in terms of performance, how much drawing paths with arcs is computationally expensive VS drawing straight lines ? Or just the browser does not care that much once it has to draw a directive ?

Comment: So far I've never encountered performance degradation because of the use of path commands. Path rendering is done pretty low-level, and even for SVGs >1MB (think of maps) browser DOM access and page layout is still slower than the actual rendering.